# C++: address of references?

Tags: c++, reference

My knowledge of C++ arcana is a bit rough. Let's say I have the following classes:

```
struct Bar {
  int x;
};

class Foo {
  Bar& bar;
public:
  Bar* getRealAddress() { return &bar; }
  Foo(Bar& _bar) : bar(_bar) {}
};

Bar bar1;
Foo foo1(bar1);
```

Will `foo1.getRealAddress()` return the same value as `&bar1`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Will `foo1.getRealAddress()` return the same value as `&bar1`?

Yes.

Basically, a reference is the original value in all but name. It's an alias.

Comment: +1 for using the word 'alias', which is what they should have been called to begin with.

Comment: @PigBen, should they? Like in, "The operator[] returns an alias of the i-th element of the list"? "Reference to" sounds more reasonable to me. "Alias" is only fine as long as we are talking about reference variables that have actual names.

Comment: @Sergey: In that instance, if we're looking at the actual dictionary definitions of the words, I don't think reference really makes much sense either.  It just sounds right because we're so used to hearing it and saying it after all this time entrenched in C++.  If we grew up hearing the term "return by alias", I think it would sound just as natural to us.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, addresses will be the same since it's the same `Bar` instance.